# Should I say 'in 3D' or 'on 3D'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, cinema

Should I say "I've watched the film **in** 3D" or "I've watched the film **on** 3D"?

Answer (score 1):

The former ( in 3D)

Here's a straightforward  example from [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/3-d) :"a film in 3-D"

Answer (score 0):

3D means three dimensions. Something cannot be seen *on* those dimensions, but can be seen *in* them. Had the phrase been '3D t.v.', then it could be seen *on* a 3D t.v. No mention of that in the question though...